# equation involving the cumulative normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I need to solve (for $x$) the following equation
$$\Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2 + b}}\right)\left\{\Phi\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right\}^{b-1} = y, \qquad a\in \mathbb{R}^+, b \in \mathbb{N}^*, x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in (0, 1),$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative standard normal distribution. I'm not sure whether this is hopeless...

If so, do you think I could resort to some kind of approximation knowing that $b$ is quite large (typically $b>50$)?

Edit: thanks to the helpful suggestions below, I ended up using a numerical approximation. This was easy to do in R with:

`uniroot(function(x) pnorm(x / sqrt(a^2 + b)) * (pnorm(x / a))^(b-1) - y, 
         interval = c(-1e5, 1e5))`.

Comment: Is this [tag:self-study]? If so, please read the tag wiki (in the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)), follow the instructions and add it to the tags in the question, otherwise this question might be closed as off-topic.

Comment: No, I'm not at school anymore:) I'm trying to find a rule to set the hyperparameters (here the x) of the model I'm working with

Comment: Do you have a better idea than going brute force with `Phi(x) = 1/2 [1 + sign(x) {1-exp(2x^2/pi)}]`? Thanks.

Comment: $y$ must be between 0 and 1 rather than $\mathbb{R}^+$. Taking logs may stabilize things a bit, and for large enough $z\gg1$, $\Phi(z) \approx \varphi(z)/z$ which may help ($\varphi(z)$ is the standard normal density).

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the answer. I will see if I can use the tail approximation then.

Comment: I don't think there is a closed form answer. There is no indefinite integral for the pdf of the normal distribution so I don't think (though I could be wrong) there is a closed form for the cumulative standard normal distribution. Some sort of numerical solution (as you suggested) or an approximation (as @StasK suggested) is probably best.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I think I will go for the numerical approximation. It seems to work pretty well in R using the function `uniroot`.

Comment: Then you can answer your own question, showing us what you did with uniroot? You could even gain some points from that ...

Comment: You are right, this is done now.

Comment: Then, can you post it **as an answer**, not only a comment? So it can be voted on ...